# Fail build if forked code is not up to date

Tags: git, jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline

I need to fail the build if the forked code is not up to date with original repo.

When a PR is done, Jenkins needs to first check if the code got from the fork(which is to be built) is up to date before doing the build. Is this possible to check from Jenkins side?

I have noticed that I can add status checks on protected branches like so [image]

As in the above pic. GitHub tells us that the branch needs to be updated, but my build is done during the checks,Hence it's a waste of a build because after all that the developer has to update the code and rebuild again. Is there a way to avoid this issue in Github side or add additional code in Jenkins ?

I'm using GitHub Organization, faced the same issue in MultiBranch Pipeline.
 using a simple `checkout scm` to get the forked code during a PR and building using maven.

Any suggestions ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Jenkins side, you can add a step:

- fetching the original repo URL (not the fork)
- comparing `original/master` HEAD and `git merge-base master yourBranch`: if they differ, that means original/master has evolved since your topic branch was created.

See more in "[Discussion on fork-point mode](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base#_discussion_on_fork_point_mode)"

That is:

```
 sh 'git remote add original /url/of/the/original/repo' 
 sh 'git fetch original' 
 sh 'if [[ "$(git rev-parse original/master)" != "$(git merge-base master yourBranch)]]; then 
   // fail the job;
   fi
 }'
```

Comment: I have a lot of doubts ..  IS this is what you are asking me to do  `git diff remotes/origin/master $(git merge-base master staging)` i.e. compare the values  using git diff ?? Can it be of the same branch ?? because i will be doing my changes in staging of forked code

Comment: @rohitthomas no just compare the SHA1 between `git rev-parse original/master` (`original` being the name you must add to your repo, referencing the URL or the original repo, not the fork which is referenced by `origin`) and the SHA1 returned by `git merge-base master yourBranch`

Comment: ahh that's much simpler :) one more question when I use `git rev-parse origin/master` origin points to originalRepo.git can I use `originalRepo.git` instead of origin  like `git rev-parse originalRepo.git/master`  as I will be doing this on Jenkins side and I'm not sure if origin will be specified

Comment: @rohitthomas not `git rev-parse origin/master`, but `git rev-parse original/master`, provided you added first `original`: `git rmeote add original /url/of/the/original/repo`

Comment: So in jenkins  I add the following lines `sh 'git remote add original /url/of/the/original/repo'`  and then `sh 'if ($(git rev-parse original/master) == $ (git merge-base master yourBranch))'`  that should do it right ??

Comment: Main doubt is will this work `sh 'git remote add original /url/of/the/original/repo'`

Comment: @rohitthomas, you need just to add the `git fetch original` step, *before* the `if` comparison line.

Comment: @rohitthomas the `git remote add` simply will modify the local configuration of the checked out repository.

Comment: If its not too much can you add it to your answer ..So that it will help the others especially for people like me  :) Thanks VonC for all your help I just have to make it work now haha :D

Comment: Your the best :) When will I ever reach your Level :)